# Compile error with initialization of an std::shared_ptr of type std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm new to C++'s smart pointers and at some point in my code I need to have a shared pointer of an unordered_map. I realized that I can't initialize the shared_ptr in the following way:

```
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> JsonDict;

    std::shared_ptr<JsonDict> ret = std::make_shared<JsonDict>(new JsonDict);
```

This is the compile error I'm getting:

*Error  C2664 'std::unordered_mapstd::string,std::string,std::hash<_Kty,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>::unordered_map(const std::unordered_map<_Kty,_Ty,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Ty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &)':
cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unordered_mapstd::string,std::string,std::hash<_Kty,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> ' to
'const std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>> &' *

I don't really understand why I'm getting this compile error.

Comment: make_shared() takes a constructor parameters. in your case just do std::shared_ptr<JsonDict> ret = std::make_shared<JsonDict>(); Because JsonDict is unordered_map and unorder_map has no constructor taking a pointer to another unordered_map -> you get compiler error

Comment: Read the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) point 1): Constructs an object of type T (...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't allocate the object on your own, `make_shared` does it for you. The arguments it accepts are used to construct the object itself, not a pointer to it. So your line should read as

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<JsonDict> ret = std::make_shared<JsonDict>();
```

(Think of it as "`make_shared` is the new `new`", though it is said about `make_unique` most often.)

Comment: Yea but my question is WHY I'm getting the compile error. I have a working code but I wonder why this line doesn't work. It's supposed to do a double allocation and be compiled isn't it?

Comment: @MahshidKhezriNejad no, it's because you're trying to construct an instance of `std::unordered_map` passing a pointer to one as construction argument. Try, for instance, `JsonDict ret = new JsonDict;`

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is trying to allocate the own object. So You need to write like this: `auto ret = std::make_shared<JsonDict>();` or `std::shared_ptr<JsonDict> ret = std::make_shared<JsonDict>();`.

Another thing why you get error is because you are decelerated JsonDict as `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` and you are trying to insert a:
`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` instead of, `<std::string, std::string>`.